# Python: Create pandas dataframe with columns based off of unique values in nestled list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a nestled list containing various regions for each sample. I would like to make a dataframe such that each row (sample) has the presence or absence of the corresponding region (column). For example, the data might look like this:

```
region_list = [['North America'], ['North America', 'South America'], ['Asia'], ['North America', 'Asia', 'Australia']]
```

And the end dataframe would look something like this:

```
North America    South America     Asia     Australia
1                0                 0        0
1                1                 0        0
0                0                 1        0
1                0                 1        1
```

I think I could probably figure out a way using nestled loops and appends, but is there be a more pythonic way to do this? Perhaps with `numpy.where`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`pandas`**
*`str.get_dummies`*

```
pd.Series(region_list).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()

   Asia  Australia  North America  South America
0     0          0              1              0
1     0          0              1              1
2     1          0              0              0
3     1          1              1              0
```

**`numpy`**
*`np.bincount` with `pd.factorize`*

```
n = len(region_list)
i = np.arange(n).repeat([len(x) for x in region_list])
f, u = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(region_list))
m = u.size

pd.DataFrame(
    np.bincount(i * m + f, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m),
    columns=u
)

   North America  South America  Asia  Australia
0              1              0     0          0
1              1              1     0          0
2              0              0     1          0
3              1              0     1          1
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit pd.Series(region_list).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 ms per loop

%%timeit
n = len(region_list)
i = np.arange(n).repeat([len(x) for x in region_list])
f, u = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(region_list))
m = u.size

pd.DataFrame(
    np.bincount(i * m + f, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m),
    columns=u
)
1000 loops, best of 3: 204 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yet another piRSquared trick I will have to remember.  "Default sep for .str.get_dummies is '|'."  +1

Comment: this is really awesome. had no idea there even was a `get_dummies()` for `str`

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :-)

Answer (score 4):

Let's try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(region_list)

df2 = df.stack().reset_index(name='region')

df_out = pd.get_dummies(df2.set_index('level_0')['region']).groupby(level=0).sum().rename_axis(None)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
         Asia  Australia  North America  South America                                               
0           0          0              1              0
1           0          0              1              1
2           1          0              0              0
3           1          1              1              0
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job!

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.chain(*region_list)))

Output
       0_Asia  0_Australia  0_North America  0_South America
    0       0            0                1                0
    1       0            0                1                0
    2       0            0                0                1
    3       1            0                0                0
    4       0            0                1                0
    5       1            0                0                0
    6       0            1                0                0
```

Comment: you have two `_Asia` columns here which need to be consolidated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools` module and `list comprehension`:

```
from itertools import chain

region_list = [['North America'], ['North America', 'South America'], ['Asia'], ['North America', 'Asia', 'Australia']]

regions = list(set(chain.from_iterable(region_list)))
vals = [[1 if j in k else 0 for j in regions] for k in region_list]
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=regions)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Australia  Asia  North America  South America
0          0     0              1              0
1          0     0              1              1
2          0     1              0              0
3          1     1              1              0
```